# Alfresco 6.2.2 with SAML and AOS - not able to open office doc

Tags: alfresco, saml

Team,

We are using alfresco-6.2.2 enterprise version, **I configured SAML which is working fine**.
we are using CA Siteminder for SAML.

Now we have requirement like, with SAML, we need to configure edit office documents using aos. I tried installing aos amps, but when I open any specific word document to edit using documentLibrary action "Edit in Microsoft Office", it opens up some HTML rendering and login.fcc (siteminder login page rendition some junk) instead asking credentials and opening word document.

I am using authentication chain like:

> authentication.chain=external1:external,ldap1:ldap,alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm

can anyone help what is missing? Ideally it should ask credentials and open word document for edit online.

**I want AOS should work with SAML and word document can be edited.**

Answer (score 0):

In order to use SAML and AOS you have add another configuration for AOS.

see. https://docs.alfresco.com/saml-module/latest/config/alfresco/#aos/admin-console

Comment: already followed that steps, after follwing those steps I am able to open word, but that file is not opening , instead some html form (siteminder login.fcc) opened. without asking credentials for SAML like first login